# How to change an NSTableView's selection without using deprecated methods

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I have the Apress "Learn Cocoa" book (published in 2010 BTW) and I am getting a deprecation error on one of the lines.  The code is:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    self.villain = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Lex Luthor", kName, @"Smallville", kLastKnownLocation, [NSDate date], kLastSeenDate, @"Superman", kSwornEnemy, @"Revenge", kPrimaryMotivation, [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Intellect", @"Leadership", nil], kPowers, @"Superhero Action", kPowerSource, [NSNumber numberWithInt:9], kEvilness, [NSImage imageNamed:@"NSUser"], kMugshot, @"", kNotes, nil];
    self.villains = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:self.villain];
    [villainsTableView reloadData];
    [villainsTableView selectRow:0 byExtendingSelection:NO];
    [self updateDetailViews];
}
```

I am getting the error on the 2nd to last line and I don't know exactly what that line is intending to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The replacement for the deprecated method would look like this:

`[villainsTableView selectRowIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] byExtendingSelection:NO];`

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTableView/selectRow%3abyExtendingSelection%3a) tells you what that message does and what the replacement is.

Answer (score 0):

In XCode you can place the mousecursor above the symbol you want to know something about. While placing the mousecursor above this symbol (i.e. NSString), hold down the ALT-Key and doubleclick. This will open up a context sensitive documentation. All deprecated methods and symbols are marked red there. Mostly the new replacement is documented next to the old one. In the new xcode, a popup-window will appear. The doc will be opened by clicking the "notebook"-icon at the border of the box.

i.e. for NSString you will find:
– initWithCString: Deprecated in iOS 2.0
+ stringWithCString:encoding:

With an educated guess you will choose "+ stringWithCString:encoding:"
Apple almost adds new functionality which is a logical augmentation of the old stuff, so you don't need to google hard, but watch into the method summary of the related doc.